# python flask url_for is throwing constant werkzeug build errors

Tags: python, flask

I am having a flask url_for('') error in a very simple application.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

base = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@base.route('/', defaults={'page':'home'})
@base.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    try:
        return render_template('%s.html'%page, name='my name is')
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

the above is my blueprints file, those routes work fine but if I try to do

```
with flask.test_request_context():
    print url_for('home') #home.html or any other forms
```

I just get this error:

```
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('home', {}, None)
```

can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?
in my html page I can print out the location of static files with:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}
```

but if i try to do:

```
{{ url_for('home') }}
```

Again I get the same error. Anyone have some advise as how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to use `url_for` the wrong way round, I think.
`url_for` in general maps an endpoint, i.e. a python function/method, to an url. In your case `home` is the value of a parameter, not an endpoint.

So, instead, use the name of the python function you want the url for:

```
url_for('show', page='home')
```

Should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `{{ url_for('home') }}` it doesn't return route of home.html instead it returns the route of a function `home`, which by the way doesn't exist.

So to fix your problem,
The proper way of using `url_for` is :

```
{{ url_for('show') }}
```